# Mule Property Placeholder access in Java properties

Tags: java, mule

I have different property files for when deploying to multiple environments in mule. In my src/main/resources I have `local.properties` and `test.properties` files. I also have a global property placeholder which I reference in `mule-app.properties` as outlined in https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/deploying-to-multiple-environments changing only that placeholder environment variable dependent on the server I use.

So for example in the `local.properties` file I could have:

```
username=John
password=local
```

for `test.properties` I would have:

```
username=Christi
password=test
```

and in my app-mule.properties i would point to:

```
mule.env=local or mule.env=test
```

So actually this works fine. But when I have to access these properties in a java class like for example `Config.java` it does not work. I would like to get the properties like in this example:

```
public class Config {

static Properties prop = new Properties();

static {
    // load a properties file
    try {
        InputStream input = Config.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("mule-app.properties");

        prop.load(input);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
public static final String USERNAME = prop.getProperty("username");
public static final String PASSWORD = prop.getProperty("password");
}}
```

and this java class works fine if I define all the properties directly in the `mule-app.properties` file, instead of referencing a specific properties file. So my questions is, how can I get this java code to access the properties defined in the local and test property files just by accessing the reference in `mule-app.properties` ?

**EDIT:**
My solution which works, suggested by @bigdestroyer:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Config {

static Properties prop = new Properties();

static {
    // load a properties file
    try {
        InputStream input = Config.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("mule-app.properties");
        prop.load(input);
        String type = prop.getProperty("mule.env");
        input = Config.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(type + ".properties");            
        prop.load(input);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
public static final String USERNAME = prop.getProperty("username");
public static final String PASSWORD = prop.getProperty("password");
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I don't misunderstand you, you could do this way:

```
public class Config {

static Properties prop = new Properties();

static {
    // load a properties file
    try {
        InputStream input = Config.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("mule-app.properties");
        InputStream input = 
        prop.load(input);

        String type = prop.getProperty("mule.env"); //<-- here you get local or test

        input = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(type + ".properties"); // here you get the file 

        prop.load(input);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
public static final String USERNAME = prop.getProperty("username");
public static final String PASSWORD = prop.getProperty("password");
}}
```

First, you get the file "typ" `local` or `test`, then you load the proper file.

NOTE: I'm "recycling" the `input` and `prop` variables, I guess there is no problem. Just test it.

I hope it helps.