# How access property into Mule Java Transformer

Tags: mule, mule-component, anypoint-studio

I have a properties file shared on several apps. To access this properties into one app, I use this tag:

`<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:br/com/empresa/configuracao/mule-apps.properties"/>`

On several Mule components, like database attributes connections, I use the following expression to access the properties, p.e.: `${db.user}`. It works!

But on Java Transformer, how I access the properties?

I tried the following instructions, but returned `null`:

```
System.getProperty("db.user");
message.getInboundProperty("db.user");
message.getOutboundProperty("db.user");
message.getInvocationProperty("db.user");
```

Is there a way to access properties into Mule Java Transformer?

Answer (score 2):

> This question has been answered for components here: [How to get property from context property placeholder tag inside custom java component](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12492547/387927) The exact same logic applies to transformers.

Use property injection:

```
<custom-transformer class="org.myCompany.CustomTransformer">
    <property name="dbUser" value="${db.user}" />
</custom-transformer>
```

Don't forget to add `setDbUser` on your custom component!

Comment: I want to use this property to make configurable host (wsdl url) in the Service class (Java Web Service). It 's initialized statically. I did what you suggested, but is returning null. Is it works in a static context?

Comment: In XML: `<custom-transformer class="br.com.emp.ws.MyServices" name="Java" doc:name="Java">
        <spring:property name="wshost" value="154.154.154.80"/>
    </custom-transformer>`

Comment: In Java (piece):     `public class MyServices extends Service {    
  static String wshost;  
  static {
   System.out.println(wshost); // print NULL
  }
  public static void setWshost(String s) {
    wshost = s;   
  }
}`

Comment: There are different options for injecting static fields: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11324464/387927

Comment: Understand. But I think that my problem is that static class is load on ESB runtime before injecting static fields, because when I start the app, first static class is load and after `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`. I need that properties to be loaded first.

Comment: Or can you just not use static? Mule/Spring provides you with proper application lifecycle and dependency management. Statics are messing with both aspects.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can leave static! I am using the web services classes generated by CXF component. But I found an alternative, programmatically, though not exactly desirable!: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34923956/mule-property-placeholder-access-in-java-properties. Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the old way of retrieving a property:

```
@Value("${db.user")
private String dbUser;
```